# PictureBox buggy movement in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, animation, timer, picturebox

**Problem**

I have PictureBoxes and I want them to move. I make them move using a timer. I can get them to move, but every time they move a pixel they leave a white background at their previous position. And when moving they make my TextBoxes blink.

This is how it looks: https://gyazo.com/cdd17b0e88a86b4dec115ceff41b44c5

Please don't pay much attention on my poor Paint skills

**Code**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int timeTicker;
    int timeMin;
    int timeSec;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeTicker++;

        Timer(timeTicker);

        //playerPics is a PictureBox array that has all the images stored
        TopMovement(playerPics[0],timeTicker);
    }

    private void Timer(int secs)
    {
        timeSec = secs;
        if(secs == 60)
        {
            timeMin += 1;
            timeTicker = 0;
        }
        tbxTimer.Text = "Time: " + timeMin + ":" + timeSec;
    }

    private void TopMovment(PictureBox top, int time)
    {
        int y = (int)(time * 1.7);
        int x = (int)(time * 0.3);

        if (time < 22 && timeMin < 1)
        {
            top.Top -= y;
            top.Left += x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look in to doing your drawing and animation using an off-screen bitmap with `System.Drawing.Graphics`.  It's a little trickier to set up, but you will get a MUCH better result in the end.  It will also open up a whole new range of options for you to do other interesting things.

Comment: You should never leave a control without a name :D

Comment: Is it moving on the Form? Set DoubleBuffered = true for the From1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `DoubleBuffered = true;` in your constructor. Also, a timer is never a good way to move graphics. It will always skip a tick and isn't really useful for what you're trying to do. I wrote this a while ago, check it out. It's not perfect but a *lot* better than using a timer. http://pastebin.com/9P77eaAU

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much!

I took a look at your code, but I'm still too much of a beginner to really understand it. :/

Comment: Oh, the PictureBox is not buggy anymore but the TextBox is still blinking. https://gyazo.com/caa3728ebc15ffa69684c0963cb003c7

Comment: Are you using my code or did you not bother? Because as I said a timer is  a bad choice for a game. (or any type of animation for that matter.) I would suggest multi threading this, a game is probably not the best introduction to C# for a beginner.